# Mirrored text in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to mirror your text or any widget in Flutter? Like in Android, I can do

```
scaleY = -1
scaleX = -1
```

I couldn't find anything similar to this in Flutter. I tried following but it simply rotates your text by 90˚

```
Transform.scale(scale: -1.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://medium.com/flutter-io/perspective-on-flutter-6f832f4d912e), it may have something that could help you.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(  // Transform widget
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001) // perspective
        ..rotateX(_offset.dy)
        ..rotateY(_offset.dx),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: _defaultApp(context),   // <<< set your widget here
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and your answer.